# How can I have the primary key of one entity be another entity in EF4 code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, primary-key, code-first

Say I have a `Post` entity, and I want to store all changes to post objects, so I also have a `PostHistory` entity.  Right now I would define the history as something like this:

```
public class PostHistory
{
   public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

   //... properties of the posthistory object
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to get this to work with EF4 Code-First.  At first model building fails because there is no primary key defined for `PostHistory`.  So in my Context I call

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PostHistory>().HasKey(x => x.Post);
```

And the following exception occurs:

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object..
```

That exception is not talking about the `PostHistory` object not having a parameterless constructor, because I added one and it didn't help.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Post {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostHistory> Histories { get; set; }
}

public class PostHistory {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

   //... properties of the posthistory object
}
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize by having an int `PostId` property I could do that.  Though that does make things messy if I change primary key types of `Post`